# javascript regext to match urls starting with fixed string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code to test static files.

```
if  (/\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|rss|txt|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|cur)(\?((r|v|rel|rev)=[\-\.\w]*)?)?$/.test(req.url)) {
  next();
} else {
  proxy.web(req, res);
}
```

However, I would like to change it to support calls that are url starting with /api/ or /auth/. Can anyone help me with the regex expression?

```
if (/*expression to test here */).test (req.url) {
    proxy.web (req.res); 
}
else { 
   next(); 
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be done using regex?  Why not just use `&&` and check for the presence of `/api/` or `/auth/`?  Example: `if ( regex_for_image && !is_api && !is_auth)`

Comment: not sure I understand your comment. I assumed regex will be easy. what is !is_api in your comment refers to?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `req.url` is? Dependent on that it could be `if (/^\/(api|auth)\//.test (req.url) {`.

Comment: @chris85 - yes. might be it. examples: 
/auth/login /api/things /api/something/123454 etc.

Comment: @TallyBarak - It's just a placeholder for some logic.  For example, you could use `req.url.indexOf('/auth') == 0` in place of `is_api`.

Comment: `if(url.search(/^(\/api\/)|(\/auth\/)/i)===0)`

Comment: Shouldn't your regex start with `/\.` instead of `/\/`?, so that it matches `.html`, `.js`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
if (/^\/(api|auth)\//.test('/auths/login')) {
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert("No Match");
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/moobv6u9/ (currently showing inaccurate URL, take off the `s` and should work.

This requires the string starts with `/api/` or `/auth/`, nothing more. The `|` is for "or" and the parenthesis group the two ored values. If you want it to be case insensative use the `i` flag/modifier after the last `/` in the regex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

The sample regexp you have provided:

```
/\/(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|rss|txt|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|cur)(\?((r|v|rel|rev)=[\-\.\w]*)?)?$/.test(req.url))
```

matches the following expressions:

```
/html
/html?
/html?r=(characters of kind alphanumeric,-,.)
```

while r can be replaced with v,rel,rev
and html can be replaced with any of the provided extensions.

In order to add a /api before that you need to escape the / char with a "\" since in javascript regexps it indicates on a beginning/end of a regexp.
Thus the regexp will have "\/api" added at the beginning.
In order to add the auth option you should use the | (or) sign with corresponding parenthesis: "\/(api|auth)".
Eventually the regexp will look like:

```
/\/(api|auth)\/(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|rss|txt|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|cur)(\?((r|v|rel|rev)=[\-\.\w]*)?)?$/
```